# Vue CLI plugin CSS preprocessor (sass) transpile in parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

We have a pretty standard [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) environment. It currently ingests a [vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) we created via the install method. The plugin is also a Vue CLI environment and lives as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the repo.

Currently the parent uses `sass` and `sass-loader` packages to transpile. It's configured in the *vue.config.js* settings, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  // Other properties and settings removed to simplify
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/styles/global.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
```

The *global.scss* just houses all our style includes.

The plugin is set up in a similar way, but none of the code is getting ingested into the parent. Which totally makes sense, as there is nothing importing/building the plugins style files. Anyone know how to import and transpile plugin sass style sheets? Thank you!

Comment: This is continuing to be a problem for us! Would love to hear if anyone has a solution.